# Calculating the derivative fo MLE of a two parameter normal pdf

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

I am going through mathematical statistics with applications by Hogg, and he takes the partial derivates in respect to the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

For the following:

$$\ln L(\mu ,\sigma) = -\frac{n}{2}\ln (2\pi \sigma^2)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\mu)^2$$

I am stuck on his solution of taking the partial derivative in respect to $\sigma^2$

He gets:

$$\frac{\partial \space \ln L(\mu, \sigma^2)}{\partial \space \sigma^2}=-\frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{\sigma^2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^2\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\mu)^2$$

I do not understand how he gets:
$\frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$ - Where did the $\pi$ go? when I do it I get: $\frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{\pi \sigma^2}$

And then when he sets the derivative to 0, he finds that he gets:

$$-n\sigma^2+\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\mu)^2=0$$

However, when I simplify:

$$-\frac{n}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^4}=\frac{-n\sigma^2+1}{2\sigma^2}$$

Unless I have gone wrong with my calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question - where does the $\pi$ go? (I ate it!) but joking aside
$$
-\frac{n}{2}\ln(2\pi\sigma^2) = -\frac{n}{2}\ln(2\pi)  -\frac{n}{2}\ln(\sigma^2)
$$
The first term is independent of the variable that you are taking the derivative of so does not impact the location of the maxima/minima.

Not sure about your second question

$$-\frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{\sigma^2}+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\right)^2\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\mu)^2 = \frac{1}{2\sigma^4} \left[-n\sigma^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\mu)^2\right] = 0$$

which is what the answer was.

Comment: Thank you for cleaning up the first with the inequality! Cannot believe that I did not spot it. I must be silly however, as I keep messing up with the simplification of the second question, could you perhaps throw me a bone? - I checked on Wolfram and it also provides me the similar result that I came up with unless I am missing another trick here?

Comment: are you saying $$\sum_{i=1}^n(y_i - \mu)^2 = 1$$?

Comment: I meant $$-\frac{n}{2}\frac{1}{\sigma^2}+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{\sigma^2})^2 \implies \frac{-n\sigma^2}{2\sigma^4}$$ - how? I seem to get my simplification wrong here

Comment: where are you going from because the l.h.s is not coming from any of the above derivation. If you can show me your derivation because the only way you can get to what you have is if you set the sum to be $1$.

Comment: Gotcha! I missed the full rearrangement. Thank you for your patience, Chinny84

Comment: No worries. Glad you understand now.